# Is it possible to implement retry logic to load JS file in angular project

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-httpclient

As we know, we can host angular application through nginx API gateway. When we load index.html file using url http://localhost:8080, It implicitly download main*.js file, runtime*.js file, polyfill*.js file, style*.css etc files.

Here my question is how to implement retry API call to those .js file in case of any failure.

I am asking this question, because I have observed during testing where system utilization is very high, sytes*.css or main*.css file download is failing intermittently.

So if you guys have any idea. please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: That's something built into Angular. I don't think you can add something like that to modify how angular serves the application unless you actually baked it into the framework